# Simple arithmetic question, couldn't really think of where to tag this

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

let $r=2^{\frac{1}{n}}>1$

We can clearly see that $r^0=1$ and $r^n=2$
Then Can someone explain which operations did we carry out to move from ,

$$\sqrt{r}(r-1)\frac{r^{\frac{3n}{2}}-1}{r^{\frac{3}{2}}-1}$$

to

$$(2\sqrt{2}-1) \sqrt{r} \frac{r-1}{r^{\frac{3}{2}}-1}$$

Comment: I believe that there are some missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sqrt{r}(r - 1)\frac{r^{3n/2} - 1}{r^{3/2} - 1} = (r^{3n/2} - 1) \sqrt{r}\frac{r - 1}{r^{3/2} - 1}$$

Now use the fact that $r^{3n/2} = 2^{3/2} = 2^1 \cdot 2^{1/2} = 2 \sqrt{2}$.